# WP_Query orderby multiple parameters not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to sort by my WP_Query results by two meta fields, first date and then time. So effectively

```
Date A 17:00
Date B 18:00
Date C 07:00
Date B 10:00 
Date A 9:00
```

would be come

```
Date A 9:00
Date A 17:00
Date B 10:00 
Date B 18:00
Date C 07:00
```

This is my current code:

```
"post_type" => "event",
"post_status" => "publish",
"posts_per_page" => 25,
"ignore_sticky_posts" => 0,
"show_sticky" => true,
"meta_query" => array(
    array(
    "key" => "_meta_event_start_date",
    "compare" => ">=",
    "value" => 0
    ),
    array(
    "key" => "_meta_event_start_time",
    "compare" => ">=",
    "value" => 0
    ),
),
"order" => "ASC",
"orderby" => "_meta_event_start_date _meta_event_start_time"
```

It is currently sorting my results appropriately by the date, but not the time (time format is stored hh:mm (24hr)). How might I amend the query to make this work?

I have seen other responses recommending using foreach loops, sql queries or even filters. I can't use these unfortunately as the site I'm working on uses the search plugin Facet WP, and as search requires WP_Query to query the database and output content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it generates SQL, it may need a comma between fields in the `orderby` value.  Does `"orderby" => "_meta_event_start_date, _meta_event_start_time"` work?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, just reverted the search default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are trying to order by meta keys - you have to use in this case a quite more complicated syntax according to changes in [WordPress 4.2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) - something like below:

```
"post_type" => "event",
"post_status" => "publish",
"posts_per_page" => 25,
"ignore_sticky_posts" => 0,
"show_sticky" => true,
"meta_query" => array(
    "event_start_date" => array(
        "key" => "_meta_event_start_date",
        "compare" => ">=",
        "value" => 0
    ),
    "event_start_time" => array(
        "key" => "_meta_event_start_time",
        "compare" => ">=",
        "value" => 0
    )
),
"orderby" => array(
    "event_start_date" => "ASC",
    "event_start_time" => "ASC"
)
```

Additionally - for single meta_key ordering it is worth to remember that you have to use in the **orderby** clause values [**meta_value** and **meta_value_num**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

Comment: Ohhhh, so if I want to order by custom column created by ACF plugin, i have to add some dull meta query for it (like > -100000) or anything that match all. In order to be able use that newly named "event_start_date" in "orderby" , because classic collumn "start_date" would be ignored otherwise.

Uh oh, tnx much for info this helped me also, wp was just totally ignoring my order.

Comment: Also what is worth mentioning is, in wp db everything is string, so when defining that custom collumn, there is need to specifi what type of collumn it is . For example number -  type' => 'numeric'